# Converting input to int throws "invalid literal for int() base 10" when passing in decimal numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, int, decimal

This exception:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '17.1'

keeps popping up but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I have to be able to use decimals in this not just whole numbers but without the `int(n1)` and `int(n2)` it won't run at all.

```
n1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
n2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
n1 = int(n1)
n2 = int(n2)
if n1 and n2 > 10:
    print("Both are above 10.")   
elif n1 and n2 <= 10:
    print("Both are below 10.")
avg = (n1 + n2) / 2
print("Average is {:.2f}".format(avg))
```

Comment: Why are you reassigning `n1` and `n2`? Not exactly ideal. Judging my the error, you're trying to input a floating-point number, which can't be converted to an integer. Use `float(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `int` on strings then the string must be an integer (not a decimal). But you could simply convert it to [`float`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float) then it also converts strings representing decimal numbers **and** also whole numbers:

```
n1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
n2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))

# Rest of your program
```

In case you want it as integer if it's an integer and only as float if it's not an integer you could try both:

```
n1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
try:
    n1 = int(n1)
except ValueError:
    n1 = float(n1)
```

And likewise for your second input.

In case you want exact decimals and operations you could probably use [`decimals.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) or [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) instead of `float` (floats are faster but of limited precision compared to the other two):

```
from fractions import Fraction

n1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
try:
    n1 = int(n1)
except ValueError:
    n1 = Fraction(n1)
```

---

Additional comment:

You should probably use `if n1 > 10 and n2 > 10:` and `elif n1 <= 10 and n2 <= 10`. Otherwise the result will be not what you expected. Because `if n1 and n2 > 10` will be interpreted as if you've written `if n1 and (n2 > 10)` which is equivalent (if `n1` is a number, and numbers are only `False` if they are zero) to `if (n1 != 0) and (n2 > 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

First if you are using `int()` you're converting a variable to `integer` then you should output it as `int` not as `float`.

Second you don't need to reassign `n1` and `n2`, you can convert the value returned from a function when you call it:

```
n1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
n2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
```

If you wanna make sure the input of your program will only be numbers you can use `try` and `except` in case of a letter is inputted:

```
try:
    n1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
    n2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
except ValueError as e:
    print("The values might only be numbers.")
    # print("Exception:\n{}".format(e)) #if you want to see the traceback
```